# Make Div Container Match the Size of an Image Before it Loads on Different-Sized Devices

Tags: html, css, image

Total noob CSS question here: I have an image with a natural resolution of 900x576 and a surrounding `<div>` container

```
<div class="img-container">
    <img src="some-image.png" />
</div>
```

This image will be displayed on many different mobile devices, all of which have different resolutions. The image will grow or shrink depending on the device its displayed on, and it will be loaded from a server (which could take a moment or 2)

I want the `img-container` to  be dynamically resized to the dimensions of the image no matter what device its displayed on, so when the image finally loads, the div doesn't abruptly grow from a height of 0px (because there's nothing inside of it yet) to the height of the image

This might be such a simple task that I'm overlooking it - can this be done purely with CSS?

Comment: You can't know image size before it loads. Besides, you can use `transition` property to make the div grow smoothly.

Comment: @Miron If you know the natural image size vs. the resolution of the device, could it not be pre-calculated? And I'm not concerned with smooth transitions just yet

Comment: You must use `javascript` to calculate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the images are always going to be the same aspect ratio you can set

```
.img-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 80%; // ratio 5:4
}
.img-container img {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution. Thank you!